# Polling with Flask and AJAX: Why is server response not showing up on in html?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I'm making a web application with Flask. The user submits a form which is passed to server. The value is passed to a python script I wrote that checks to see if a username is taken on a number of web forums.

As the results come in they are passed back to the page with AJAX. I want to update the webpage as the data comes in. I understand that websockets is probably more efficient, but this is just for practice and I want to learn how to do it with polling.

main.py:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_form():
    #print(request.form)
    x = request.form['id']
    a = Vbulletin(x)

    def result_gen():
        return a.reg_ver()
    result_gen()

    def generate_resp():
        with app.app_context():
            for text in result_gen():
                print(text)
                text2 = json.dumps(text)
                #print(text2)
                yield (text2)
                sleep(1)

    return app.response_class(generate_resp(), mimetype='application/json')


app.run()
```

forumsearch.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        req = $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "/search",
            data: { id: $("#searchinput").val()},
         });
        req.done(function(temp){

            var latest = document.getElementById('latest');
            var output = document.getElementById('output');

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', '/search');
            xhr.send();
            var position = 0;

            function handleNewData() {
                var messages = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
                messages.slice(position, -1).forEach(function(value) {
                    latest.textContent = value;
                    var item = document.createElement('li');
                    item.textContent = value;
                    output.appendChild(item);
                });
                position = messages.length - 1;
            }

            var timer;
            timer = setInterval(function() {

                handleNewData();

                if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    latest.textContent = 'Done';
                }
            }, 1000);

            });
       });
  });
```

The issue i'm having is that the results are showing up from the POST requests in the browser when I look at the response in the network tab, but it is not being updated on the webpage. There a couple of things I see that could be the issue, but I am unsure how to proceed.

The first is that the XHR 'GET' request is never sent. The 'POST' request is sent and the response is coming in to the client, but the 'GET' request after it is never sent.

Maybe I'm not understanding polling, but don't i need to make a GET request to poll the server? Or do need to just handle the POST request?

Another problem I see is that response that I'm getting from 'POST' request has a syntax error.

The response is this:

```
"https://www.bimmerboost.com/register.php , user found!!! I SAID USER FOUND!!!""http://www.vbforums.com/register.php , user found!!! I SAID USER FOUND!!!"
```

and error in firefox is this:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after
>   JSON data at line 1 column 80 of the JSON data

How can I fix this error, and what do I need to change to get the server response to show up in html?

Comment: Why are you setting mime type to json when you are sending text?

Comment: change  $("#submit").on('click',function(e){  TO  $("#submit").submit(function(e){  The e.prevent default needs a process to prevent, instead of preventing the click action which is what you have worded in code. Also, I think when you assign the  type=submit  attribute it changes the click()  action to a submit() action type

Comment: when make the changes you suggested it sends my 'POST' request to index.html instead of '/search', how can I fix that?

Comment: I changed the mime type to text/ plain. Its sending the 'GET' request now( thank you), but I'm getting a 400 error, do I need to parse JSON?